# Async/await style for UI in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await

I want to implement async / await style in Unity for UI. It occurs to me that you can write a static class in which to define a method like this `public static async Task<Button> WaitForButtonClickAsync(CancellationToken ct, params Button[] buttons)` This method will wait for any of the transferred buttons to be pressed with `Task.whenAny`, and then it will return a button. But what’s after that? I can only come up with something like a giant `switch-case` block to figure out which button was pressed or pass the buttons with a callback to the method right away, but it seems to me that these are not the best solutions.

Comment: What exactly would this be useful for?

Comment: https://youtu.be/7eKi6NKri6I?t=2161 You can watch a few minutes of this video (start at 36:00). Speaker talks about user interface issues this pattern solves.

Comment: Wow the talk is really quite interesting .. however I still don't get why you would use a routine or async at all for such a popup ^^ What we do e.g. is simply passing it some callback listeners at the beginning so later we also know whether this popup was accepted, canceled, closed or failed somewhere ... I don't really see a need for such a pattern in this case tbh

Comment: As the speaker said, this will help to solve the problem of double clicking on buttons, pressing two buttons at once, pressing the buttons that are behind this popUp screen, without even thinking about it, just using this pattern. It seems to me that it will be quite convenient.

Comment: Only by using this pattern you are not yet solving the issue of double pressing multiple buttons or something in the background ... you still need to somehow block input on all other buttons ;) What it solves is again unlocking the other buttons when the popup has an error or is canceled ... as said you could implement the same thing by simply using event listeners ;)

Comment: Why not? It I use method like this `async Task<Button> WaitForButtonsClickAsync(CancellationToken ct, params [] Buttons)`.If you use this method for all buttons in the scene, provided that with each new call, the old method will be closed with the token, then when I call such a popup window, I will pass to this method only the buttons that are in this window, so any other buttons in the scene will not do anything until one of the passed buttons is pressed and I call this method with other parameters. And through Task.WhenAny I will get the first button clicked and return it.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this pattern very successfully. But you are right about the giant switch-case, it does require a bit of boilerplate. But then again, it's not actually any shorter with callbacks.

Example:

```
Button pressedButton = await WaitForButtonClickAsync(ct, button1, button2, button3);
if (pressedButton == button1) await DoStuff1(ct);    
if (pressedButton == button2) await DoStuff2(ct);
if (pressedButton == button3) await DoStuff3(ct);
```

Or with callbacks (Note that we aren't removing event handlers here, so this solution isn't at all shorter in reality), though here we don't get the advantage of chaining async code:

```
button1.onClick += () => DoStuff1();
button2.onClick += () => DoStuff2();
button3.onClick += () => DoStuff3();
```

You could also make some kind of helper to avoid the if-elses, something like this:

```
await WaitForButtonHandlersAsync(ct, 
                                (button1, DoStuff1), 
                                (button2, DoStuff2),
                                (button3, DoStuff3));
```

But as you start mixing in other awaits in addition to buttons, this can get messy, and I've always just fallen back to if-else listings.

EDIT:
One thing to ad is that you can also group things. For example if you have a commonly used set of navigation buttons/gestures in addition to a few context specific buttons, you can bundle the navigation buttons into one task. This example also contains the usage of linked tokens presented in the video.

```
using (var cts = CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct))
{
    var navigationTask = WaitForNavigationEventAsync(cts.Token);
    var buttonTask1 = WaitForButtonClickAsync(cts.Token, button1);
    var buttonTask2 = WaitForButtonClickAsync(cts.Token, button2);

    var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(navigationTask, buttonTask1, buttonTask2);
    await finishedTask; // "Reveal" and propagate exceptions
    cts.Cancel();

    if (finishedTask == navigationTask) await Navigate(navigationTask.Result, ct);
    if (finishedTask == buttonTask1) await DoStuff1(ct);
    if (finishedTask == buttonTask2) await DoStuff2(ct);
}
```

With this kind of constructs, the listing never gets out of hands and you avoid some repeating code.